# How should the data folder be to take input as (x-train, y-train), (x-test, y-test) in a cnn model

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, conv-neural-network, tf.keras

I am new to machine learning and deep learning. I have tried a multi-class classification model using CNN algorithm. I first tried it using the CIFAR-10 data set which is provided by the keras.
In there, we give the input as follows to load the data set,

```
(x-train, y-train), (x-test, y-test) = tf.keras.datasets.cifar10.load_data()
```

This worked for me. However, I am now trying it with my manual data set instead of the built-in data set. I don't know how the data set folder should be, and even how to access it.

For now, I have a data set folder arrangement as follows,

```
Dataset=> Training_set => 10 different classes folders with corresponding images within
          Test_set => 10 different classes folders with corresponding images within
```

I have no idea how to use it in the code while calling the `load_data`. If I use it in the normal way, like, `flow_from_directory('../Dataset/Training_set')` I get the following error - `Too many values to unpack(expected 2)`. Kindly help with this issue. It would be a great help for learning.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try using `tf.keras.utils.image_dataset_from_directory`.

Create dummy data:

```
import os
import numpy
from PIL import Image

os.mkdir('Training_set')
for i in range(10):
  os.mkdir('Training_set/class{}'.format(i))

for i in range(10):
  for j in range(2):
    imarray = numpy.random.rand(100,100,3) * 255
    im = Image.fromarray(imarray.astype('uint8')).convert('RGB')
    im.save('Training_set/class{}/result_image{}.png'.format(i, j))
```

Folder structure:

```
- Training_set/
    - class9/
        - result_image1.png
        - result_image0.png
    - class8/
        - result_image1.png
        - result_image0.png
    - class7/
        - result_image1.png
        - result_image0.png
    - class0/
        - result_image1.png
        - result_image0.png
    - class2/
        - result_image1.png
        - result_image0.png
    - class5/
        - result_image1.png
        - result_image0.png
    - class4/
        - result_image1.png
        - result_image0.png
    - class3/
        - result_image1.png
        - result_image0.png
    - class1/
        - result_image1.png
        - result_image0.png
    - class6/
        - result_image1.png
        - result_image0.png
```

Load data with `validation_split=0.2` (80% train data, 20% validation data):

```
import tensorflow as tf

train_ds = tf.keras.utils.image_dataset_from_directory(
  'Training_set',
  validation_split=0.2,
  subset="training",
  seed=123,
  image_size=(100, 100),
  batch_size=2)

val_ds = tf.keras.utils.image_dataset_from_directory(
  'Training_set',
  validation_split=0.2,
  subset="validation",
  seed=123,
  image_size=(100, 100),
  batch_size=2)

for x, y in train_ds.take(1):
  print(x.shape, y.shape)
```

```
Found 20 files belonging to 10 classes.
Using 16 files for training.
Found 20 files belonging to 10 classes.
Using 4 files for validation.
(2, 100, 100, 3) (2,)
```

You can also choose if you want the labels to be sparse or categorical. See the [docs](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/utils/image_dataset_from_directory) for more information.

These datasets can be fed directly to your model like this:

```
epochs=10
history = model.fit(
  train_ds,
  validation_data=val_ds,
  epochs=epochs)
```

And you can convert your `tensorflow` datasets to `numpy` arrays if you really want to:

```
x_train, y_train = np.concatenate(list(train_ds.map(lambda x, y: x))), np.concatenate(list(train_ds.map(lambda x, y: y)))
x_test, y_test = np.concatenate(list(val_ds.map(lambda x, y: x))), np.concatenate(list(val_ds.map(lambda x, y: y)))
```

Comment: I did understand few part of it. But, how does just x,y satisfy (x-train, y-train) , (x-test, y-test)? Or does the images in training folder alone, get converted into both training and testing data, like it's shown, 16 files for training, which means the rest of the files are for testing? Did I get it right?

Comment: So, that means I don't even require the Test_set folder that I already have in my Dataset folder? And another doubt is that what exactly is x-train, y-train, x-test, y-test?

Comment: Oh my god! Yes this works!!! Many many thanks to you. I was fed up looking for this part from 3 days. You helped me keep my learning going on, thanks again!

Comment: Sorry, I have another issue with this. When I split the x-train, y-train and x-test, y-test as you said, it only accepts the files, but not the images inside those files. When I checked the x-train shape, it gives an output as `x_train shape(12,64,64,3)` which means it's taking only 12 files and not anything inside it. I even tried to plot the x_train, but can't use more than 12 index it says. How can I access the images within those files then?

Comment: What do you mean files ? It works like this: one file is exactly one image

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/242025/discussion-between-yamini-r-and-alonetogether).